# Диалоговое окно закрытия формы

Tags: c#, winforms

```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){

        if (Flag == true)
        {
            var formClose = MessageBox.Show("Вы точно хотите завершить работу ?", "FormClose", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (formClose == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Exit();
                KILL();
            }
            if(formClose == DialogResult.No)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Неважно что ты нажмешь, программа все равно закроется. Почему так?

Comment: Проверку нужно не тут делать. Это осбытие вызывается при закрытии формы. То есть закрытие уже началось а это то, что вы хотите при нем сделать. Диалог нужно показывать до этого события.

Comment: А можете сказать, как показать диалог до события ?

Comment: попробуйте в последнем `if` сделать `return`.

Comment: Вам же дали ответ в другом вашем вопросе: задавайте свойство [e.Cancel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо установить свойство `e.Cancel` в `true`, чтобы форма не закрывалась:

```
if(formClose == DialogResult.No)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```